# Category of multisets, spans and pullbacks

Tags: category-theory, multisets

I want to define a category of multisets, $Multi$.  To do this, I take the ambient category $SET$, and represent the multisets as functions.  So, the objects $Multi$ are functions.  We define composition via spans in $SET$.  If I have two multisests $f: C \rightarrow A$ and $g: C \rightarrow B$, then a morphism from $A$ to $B$ is the span $\langle f,g \rangle$.  Next, I need to compose the spans, so I use pullbacks of two spans.  Is this a valid construction?

It has been pointed out that I am defining a rather limited category that might not be interesting.  Instead, I might want to define the morphisms as commutative squares.  So, if $f,g$ are two objects, then a morphism is a pair of functions, $i,j$, where $i:C \rightarrow C$, $j: A \rightarrow B$ and $ g \cdot i = j \cdot f$.

Comment: So there is only one morphism from the multiset $f:C\to A$ to the multiset $g:C\to B$?

Comment: @ArnaudD.  Thanks for the great question.  I am utterly convinced that spans represent the morphisms.  It is very strange to say it, but I think yes, one morphism.  It must be wrong?

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong per se, but it may not model what you're looking for in the category. Categories with at most one morphism per pair of objects typically aren't that useful/interesting. Perhaps you're looking at Mor($\mathcal{C}$), where objects are the morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, and morphisms between these 'objects' are commutative squares in $\mathcal{C}$ with two (possibly non-adjacent) sides as the morphisms considered as objects in $\mathcal{C}$.